# Get json respons from http get respons?

Tags: autocode

Please tell me how to get json response?
I get base4 by example:

```
// Using Node.js 14.x +
// use "lib" package from npm
const lib = require('lib')({token: null /* link an account to create an auth token */});

// make API request
let result = await lib.http.request['@1.1.6'].get({
  url: null // required
});
```

https://autocode.com/lib/http/request/#get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) package will be easier. It's default response type is json.

```
const axios = require('axios');
let result = await axios.get('your_url')
});
```